# React useEffect() alert once after dependences change

Tags: reactjs, alert, use-effect

I am using Typescript for my app. I have two sets of data in the database, one is `date` and one is `time`. Both are expecting strings.

I made one `POST` request when the user chooses the date, and that time will be selected for the user. I made a helper function for when the user's choosing time will be over, in which case I show them an alert on the front-end that shows

> "Your selected time expired!"

After showing that Alert. I forcefully clear the delivery time. My logic works fine. Whenever I visit the screen, it always alerts the screen which is not good for UI and UX. But I understand useEffect() makes an effect whenever I visit that screen since the dependencies change. Is there any way I can display the Alert only one time when the time expired then whenever users visit they can't see the alert?

`PS: I am thinking should I do with something with my helper function`

**Here is My sample code, also I share my code in [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/helperfunction-ubgcs?file=/src/App.tsx)**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { isToday } from "date-fns";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export const isEmptyString = (value: string): boolean =>
  !value || value.trim().length === 0;

export const isTimeWindowExpired = (date: string, time: string) => {
  if (isEmptyString(date)) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    const [yyyy, mm, dd]: Array<string> = date.split("-");
    const d: Date = new Date();
    d.setFullYear(+yyyy);
    d.setMonth(+mm - 1);
    d.setDate(+dd);
    if (isToday(d)) {
      const matcher = d.toTimeString().match(/(\d{2}:\d{2}):.*/);
      if (matcher) {
        const [currentLocalTime] = matcher.slice(1);

        const [startTime, endTime] = time.split("-");

        return currentLocalTime >= startTime && currentLocalTime <= endTime;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
};

const deliveryDate = "2021-06-18";
const deliveryTime = "07:12-07:13";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const isExpired = isTimeWindowExpired(deliveryDate, deliveryTime);
    if (!isExpired) {
      alert("delivery_time_expired");
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Edit to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` hook will execute on first load of the component AND every time any deps change.

Comment: I would set an expiration value in localStorage. Read the value in when the component mounts and check the expiration. If the expiration has passed, display the alert and clear localStorage, otherwise set a timeout for the alert while the component remains mounted. This isn't an issue with `useEffect` or React hooks in general, but rather one of managing an expiration DateTime and alerting.

Comment: Thanks for reply Drew. Can you show me in code please? I share my code in codesandbox in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set an expiration value in localStorage. Read the value in when the component mounts and check the expiration. If the expiration has passed, display the alert and clear localStorage, otherwise set a timeout for the alert while the component remains mounted. Don't forget to clear the timeout in the `useEffect` hook cleanup function if the component unmounts *before* the expiration.

External to component/effect, just gets the expiration value into local storage. I'm using the [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html) library for DateTime management.

```
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

const EXPIRATION_KEY = "expiration";

const deliveryDate = "2021-06-17";
const deliveryTime = "22:45";

let timer: number;
const expiration = DateTime.fromISO(deliveryDate + "T" + deliveryTime);
window.localStorage.setItem(EXPIRATION_KEY, expiration.toISO());
```

In the component.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const expirationTrigger = () => {
    alert("delivery_time_expired");
    window.localStorage.removeItem(EXPIRATION_KEY);
  };

  const expirationString = window.localStorage.getItem(EXPIRATION_KEY);
  if (expirationString) {
    const expiration = DateTime.fromISO(expirationString);
    if (expiration.diffNow() < 0) {
      expirationTrigger();
    } else {
      timer = setTimeout(expirationTrigger, expiration.diffNow().milliseconds);
    }
  }

  // effect cleanup to clear timeout when component unmounts
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

[image: Edit react-useeffect-alert-once-after-dependences-change]

Comment: Awesome! I am using React native app . Now I need to find how to achieve the logic which you just did it

Comment: you are good at functionality. Could you please check is my function's logic and use the function in `useEffect` is right?

Comment: Is there any platform we can talk than stack overflow. Because you solved the problem already. I am facing one weird issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233918/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-krisna).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ref to track whether the effect is fired for the first time.

```js
const firstTimeRef = useRef<boolean>(true)
useEffect(() => {
  const isExpired = isTimeWindowExpired(deliveryDate, deliveryTime);
  if (!isExpired && !firstTimeRef.current) {
    alert("delivery_time_expired");
  }
  firstTimeRef.current = false
}, [deliveryDate, deliveryTime]);
```

The effect re-runs whenever `deliveryDate` and `deliveryTime` are changed and only display the alert if it is not running for the first time.

Comment: This will not work as expected because `deliveryDate` and `deliveryTime` are not states.

Comment: I suspect the code snippet in the question is not the whole program and the author just make it static for the sake of this question.

Comment: @AlvinLeung it did not trigger my function.

Comment: @Krisna `deliveryDate` and `deliveryTime` have to be a state for React to detect changes to them. When React detects changes to these states, it re-render the component and re-apply the effect. Perhaps you can edit your code snippet to show how you are going to assign/modify the 2 variables?